# Binary Search dosen't find the right value

Tags: c, binary-search

I create a vector with 1000 elements, the value of the elements is the index itself
V[100] = 100, V[50] = 50 etc.

When I call the binary search by the value it must return to me the index, what is itself
so binary_search(vector, begin, end, 50) must returns to me 50, but returns 30. I tried to debug with gdb, but can't find anything wrong.

Code:

```c
int rbb(int *v, int left, int right, int val) 
{

    int mid = (left + right) / 2;  //middle element

    if (right < left) //stop codition, pointers shifted
        return -1;

    if (val == v[mid]) //found value
        return mid;  

    if (val > v[mid]) //value is on vector right portion
        rbb(v, mid+1, right, val);

    if (val < v[mid]) //value is on vector left portion
        rbb(v, left, mid-1, val);

}

int main () 
{

    int v[1000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        v[i] = i;

    int x = rbb(v, 0, 999, 300);
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: Why not try hand computing with say, 9 or 10 elements? What did you learn by stepping through in gdb?

Comment: Fyi, this is far, far easier when you take advantage of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but how can I take advantage of pointer arithmetic in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Problem with your code is that you are not returning the value from the recursive call if rbb function. You should modify your code

```
if (val > v[mid]) //value is on vector right portion
    return rbb(v, mid+1, right, val);

if (val < v[mid]) //value is on vector left portion
    return rbb(v, left, mid-1, val);
```

Comment: Shocking, the frequency of answers that *did not* pick up on this.

Comment: Happens with everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
int rbb(int *v, int left, int right, int val) {

int mid = (left + right) / 2;  //middle element

if (right < left) //stop codition, pointers shifted
    return -1;

èlse if (val == v[mid]) //found value
    return mid;  

else if (val > v[mid]) //value is on vector right portion
    rbb(v, mid+1, right, val);

else if (val < v[mid]) //value is on vector left portion
    rbb(v, left, mid-1, val);
}
```

```
int main () {

int v[1000];

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    v[i] = i;

int x = rbb(v, 0, 999, 300);
printf("%d", x);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the return. When the function returns it doesn't end and continue calling other if statement changing the mid variable. You can change like this

```
    int rbb (int *v, int left, int right, int val){
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;  //middle element

        if (right < left) //stop codition, pointers shifted
            return -1;

        else if (val == v[mid]) //found value
            return mid;

        else if (val > v[mid]) //value is on vector right portion
            rbb(v, mid+1, right, val);

        else if (val < v[mid]) //value is on vector left portion
            rbb(v, left, mid-1, val);
    }

    int main() {
        int v[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            v[i] = i;

        int x = rbb(v, 0, 999, 300);
        printf("%d", x);
    }
```

Comment: Your compiler *doesn't* warn you about code paths with no set return value with that code? Look at `rbb` and ask yourself: what is `return` ed when *neither* of the first two `if` conditions are true ?

Comment: Yes, he warned me when I compiled gcc with -Wall flag, but I thought it was wrong and I covered all possibles cases with those conditionals.

Answer (score -1):

U Can Use this Code and your Code is also correct but you should use
 else if statements while comparing......

> Have A Great Day
>   Enjoy Coding

```
#include<stdio.h>
int rbb(int v[], int left, int right, int val);
int main ()
{
int i,v[1000],x;
   for (i = 0; i <1000; i++)
     {
        v[i] = i;
     }
     x = rbb(v, 0,999, 300);
     printf("%d", x);

}
int rbb(int v[], int left, int right, int val) {
int mid;
mid = (left + right) / 2;  //middle element
if (right < left) //stop codition, pointers shifted
   {
      return 1;
   }
else if (val == v[mid]) //found value
   {    
      return mid;
   }
else if (val > v[mid]) //value is on vector right portion
    {
        rbb(v, mid+1, right, val);
    }
else//value is on vector left portion
    {
        rbb(v, left, mid-1, val);
    }

}
```